# Determine when a gitlab CI job ran

Tags: gitlab-ci

I have a CI job that ran last week:

[image: CI Job Summary stats]

Is there a way to find out exactly when it finished?  I am trying to debug a problem that we just noticed, and knowing if the job finished at 9:00am or 9:06am or 6:23pm a week ago would be useful information.

The output from the job does not appear to indicate what time it started or stopped.  When I asked Google, I got information about how to run jobs in serial or parallel or create CI jobs, but nothing about getting the time of the job.

For the future, I could put `date` into `script` or `before_script`, but that is not going to help with this job.

This is on a self-hosted gitlab instance.  I am not sure of the version or what optional settings have been enabled.